# JQuery traversing the DOM. Nested Parent / Child

Tags: jquery

I am trying to change the properties of the (Field1) element when I click the (Button1) element. I want to set the INPUT field as DISABLED and HIDDEN when the button is clicked but having trouble traversing the DOM with JQUERY. My HTML example structure below is correct in terms of Parent / Children. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<div  class="container">

  <label for="check">Coffee Check <span class="form-required" title="This field is required.">*</span></label>

    <div id="check" class="form-radios webform switch_comment">

      <div class="form-type-radio form-item radio">

         <!-- ******(Button1) click this radio button (Button1)****** --> 
         <input required="required" class="webform switch_comment form-radio" type="radio" id="coffee-check-1" name="submitted[coffee_check]" value="3" checked="checked" /> 
         <!-- ******************************* -->

         <label for="edit-submitted-standards-product-quality-coffee-check-1">Yes </label> 

     </div>

     <div class="form-type-radio form-item-submitted-standards-product-quality-coffee-check form-item radio">

       <input required="required" class="webform switch_comment form-radio" type="radio" id="coffee-check-2" name="submitted[coffee_check]" value="0" />  
       <label for="edit-submitted-standards-product-quality-coffee-check-2">No </label>

    </div>

 </div>

 <div class="description">Is there evidence of daily checks, 2nd check at 11am being completed if +50 cups per day</div>

</div>

<div  class="form-item webform-component webform-component-textfield "> 
<label for="edit-submitted-standards-product-quality-comments-coffee-check">Comments (Coffee Check) <span class="form-required" title="This field is required.">*</span></label>

<!-- *****(Field1) change properties of this input (Field1)******-->
<input required="required" class="webform switch_comment form-control form-text required" type="text" id="comments-coffee-check" name="submitted[comments_coffee_check]" value="" disabled="disabled" style="display: none;"/>
 <!-- ******************************* -->

 </div>
```

///////////////////////////////////

JQuery

```
// Fire when radio button is clicked
    $('input:radio').click(function(){

        // check which radio is clicked based on value.
        if($(this).val() === '0'){

          // hide bootstrap button if radio is NO
              $(this).parent().parent().parent().next(".AddComment").fadeOut("slow");

 /// Hide field

        }else{

          // show bootstrap button if radio is YES
          $(this).parent().parent().parent().next(".AddComment").fadeIn("slow");

  /// Show field

        }

    });
```

Comment: Can you provide the jQuery you've written so far?

Comment: `code` // Fire when radio button is clicked
        $('input:radio').click(function(){
   
            // check which radio is clicked based on value.
            if($(this).val() === '0'){
                
              // hide bootstrap button if radio is NO
              $(this).parent().parent().parent().next(".AddComment").fadeOut("slow");

            }else{
                
              // show bootstrap button if radio is YES
              $(this).parent().parent().parent().next(".AddComment").fadeIn("slow");
            }

        });

Answer (score 0):

Since IDs **must** be unique, and both the elements you refer to have an ID, you can simply target the FIELD1 element when you click on the BUTTON1 element directly:

```
$('#coffee-check-1').click(function(){
    $('#comments-coffee-check').hide().prop('disabled',true)
})
```

No DOM traversal needed.

UPDATE:

Based on your comments, then the following will work:

```
$('input.webform.switch_comment.form-radio').click(function(){
    $('this').closest('div.container').next('div.form-item.webform-component.webform-component-textfield').find('input.webform.switch_comment.form-control.form-text.required').hide().prop('disabled',true)
})
```

I used the classes on your elements as part of the selectors, however you could also use the name attribute. So for example, instead of `$('input.webform.switch_comment.form-radio')`, you could use `$('input[name="submitted\\[coffee_check\\]"]')`. See https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/ for caveats on special characters and how to escape them.

Comment: The fields are dynamically generated and IDs are defined based on the name given. I have no way of knowing what the ID will be.

I have to use something like next()